# How to use add_filter to add the extra data to existing array?

Tags: filters, actions

Hi I am new to hooks and have a query to add additional data to the existing array. Please check the below code.

I have some basic details and want to add the Phone number using add_filter(). If I give directly,it is working. But I need to do this using filter. Please help...

```
function give_import_donations_options() 
{
return (array) apply_filters(
        'give_import_donations_options',
        [
            'id'           => __( 'Donation ID', 'give' ),          
            'first_name'   => [
                __( 'Donor First Name', 'give' ),
                __( 'First Name', 'give' ),
                __( 'Name', 'give' ),
                __( 'First', 'give' ),
            ],
            'last_name'    => [
                __( 'Donor Last Name', 'give' ),
                __( 'Last Name', 'give' ),
                __( 'Last', 'give' ),
            ],
            'company_name' => [
                __( 'Company Name', 'give' ),
                __( 'Donor Company Name', 'give' ),
                __( 'Donor Company', 'give' ),
                __( 'Company', 'give' ),
            ],
           'country'      => __( 'Country', 'give' ),
           'notes'        => __( 'Notes', 'give' ),
            /*'give_phone'        => __( 'Phone', 'give' ),*/
        ]
    );
}'
```

I am trying to add phone number using filter:

```
function additional_field
{
need to add code to add Phone Number...
}

add_filter('give_import_donations_options','additional_field...')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided looks correct, and it should work as expected. However, if you want to add the 'give_phone' option using a filter, you would need to modify the code to include the filter hook and the callback function. Here's the modified code:

```
function additional_field($options) {
    $options['give_phone'] = __( 'Phone', 'give' );
    return $options;
}
add_filter('give_import_donations_options', 'additional_field');

function give_import_donations_options() {
    return (array) apply_filters(
        'give_import_donations_options',
        [
            'id'           => __( 'Donation ID', 'give' ),          
            'first_name'   => [
                __( 'Donor First Name', 'give' ),
                __( 'First Name', 'give' ),
                __( 'Name', 'give' ),
                __( 'First', 'give' ),
            ],
            'last_name'    => [
                __( 'Donor Last Name', 'give' ),
                __( 'Last Name', 'give' ),
                __( 'Last', 'give' ),
            ],
            'company_name' => [
                __( 'Company Name', 'give' ),
                __( 'Donor Company Name', 'give' ),
                __( 'Donor Company', 'give' ),
                __( 'Company', 'give' ),
            ],
            'country'      => __( 'Country', 'give' ),
            'notes'        => __( 'Notes', 'give' ),
        ]
    );
}

$modified_options = give_import_donations_options();
print_r($modified_options);
```

**Note:** Place this code in your theme's functions.php file or in a custom plugin file and inform me if you have any issues.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the immediate help. After adding this code, the existing and new option are not showing. I was searching in Google and added some code using array push. Showing the options. But don't know whether am writing syntax correctly or not.               function importdropdownoptionadditional($args)
{
 array_push($args, "give_phone", "Phone", "give");
 return $args;
}  add_filter( 'give_import_donations_options','importdropdownoptionadditional',10,3);

Comment: The code you provided looks correct, and it should work as expected. However, if you want to add the 'give_phone' option using a filter, you would need to modify the code to include the filter hook and the callback function. I have updated my code. So you can check.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working. I was struggling to learn and understand about this hooks for the past 2 days. Now understood little more.